# Spring boot issue with mapping entity to entityDTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am using spring-boot-1.5.6 and modelmapper-1.1.0. I would like to map the entity object to OrderDto
but don't know how to do it via modelMapper. Please find the below code

**Order.Java**

```
public class Order {
    private String orderUid;
    private Invoice invoice;
    private List<Item> items;

    //Getter & setter
}
```

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    private String itemId;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemUid;
    private String isbn;
    //other details of item
    //Getter & setter
}
```

**OrderDTO.java**

```
public class OrderDTO {
    private String orderUid;
    private Invoice invoice;
    private String itemId;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemUid;
    private String isbn;
    //other details of item

    //Getter & setter
}
```

**I would like to return OrderDTO with the item based on the itemID we are getting from the client(FrontEnd)**

```
public Page<OrderDTO> convertOrderEntityToDTO (Page<Order> orderList,String itemId) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<Page<OrderDTO>>() {}.getType();
    modelMapper.addConverter((MappingContext<Order, OrderDTO> context) -> {
      Item item = context.getSource().getItems().stream()
          .filter(item -> equalsIgnoreCase(item.getItemId,itemId))
          .findAny().orElse(null);
      if (item != null) {
        OrderDTO orderDTO = context.getDestination();
        orderDTO.setItemId(item.getItemId());
        orderDTO.setItemName(item.getItemName());
        orderDTO.setItemUid(item.getItemUid());
        orderDTO.setIsbn(item.getIsbn());
        return orderDTO;
      }
      return null;
    });

    Page<OrderDTO> addonServices = modelMapper.map(orderList, listType);
}
```

In the above method, converter was never called(may be because of incorrect TypePair of modelMapper) and the item related attributes
in OrderDTO is always null. I would like to get the Item value based on ItemId.

Any help or hint would be appreciable. Any suggestion with or without modelMapper would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you use `Page` class of `org.springframework.data` or something like that. Anyway, this generic `Page` class contains generic `List` with your data. I would say, that this construction is just "too generic" for modelMapper. You'd better get list of your data, convert it and create a new `Page`.

Furthermore

- You should create a `typeMap` to register a new converter
- `context.getDestination()` returns not null if you provide new destination object by `modelMapper.map(..)`. In your case you'll get `null`.

This is my vision of your `convertOrderEntityToDTO` method:

```
public Page<OrderDTO> convertOrderEntityToDTO(Page<Order> orderList, String itemId) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(Order.class, OrderDTO.class)
            .setConverter(context -> context.getSource().getItems().stream()
                    .filter(o -> equalsIgnoreCase(o.getItemId(), itemId))
                    .findAny().map(o -> {
                        OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO();
                        orderDTO.setItemId(o.getItemId());
                        orderDTO.setItemName(o.getItemName());
                        orderDTO.setItemUid(o.getItemUid());
                        orderDTO.setIsbn(o.getIsbn());
                        return orderDTO;
                    }).orElse(null));

    List<OrderDTO> orderDtoList = orderList.getContent().stream()
            .map(o -> modelMapper.map(o, OrderDTO.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new PageImpl<>(orderDtoList, orderList.getPageable(), orderList.getTotalElements());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Spring Data JpaRepositories` to retrieve data from the database you can make a repository method that creates a DTO for you. Such a method would look something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT new full.path.OrderDTO(s.itemId, s.itemName, s.itemUid) FROM Item s WHERE s.itemId = :id")
public OrderDTO getOrderDTOByItemId(@Param("id") long id);
```

The method should go in the jparepository class you use to retrieve `Item` instances from the database with. To make this work your OrderDTO needs to have a constructor with this parameter list. `( long itemId, String itemName, String itemUid)`. The parameters need to be in the same order as `(s.itemId, s.itemName, s.itemUid)`. Also always make sure you create a default constructor as well when you create a constructor with parameters.